# Recommended electronic versions of old public domain US history textbooks?

Tags: 19th-century, 18th-century, book, historical-research

I realize it's common practice for historians use primary sources, but what I want is some old US history schoolbooks pre-copyright, say 1700-1900. Something high-school level or higher (i.e. not for little kids).

Unfortunately Project Gutenberg does not allow searching by publication date and I don't have any idea of what authors to search for. Any recommendations or suggestions for where to begin?

http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/search/?start_index=26&query=american+history

Comment: Possibly of use, though a bit later: http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/collection?collection=Perseus:collection:cwar

Answer (score 4):

Google search may have what you are looking for. Often when researching questions on this forum, I use the **Books** tab of their search, and then selecting the *tools* button, you can either narrow the search by copyright availability, and/or set the publication year changing *any time* tab to *19th century*, or setting the *custom range* to a specific time. The books resulting from this search will often have several formats you can download them in, to be read at your leisure.

Comment: And if this technique turns up a hit, the book may be available on archive.org, e.g., https://archive.org/details/histforschools00gordrich